Unable to create MIG on GCP
I tried this command on gcloud shell -
gcloud compute instance-groups managed create my-mig \
--zone us-central1-a \
--template my-instance-template-with-custom-image \
--size 1 

But it is showing error - ERROR: gcloud.compute.instance-groups.managed.create) Could not fetch resource:  - Invalid value for field 'resource.instanceTemplate'.
I have created instance template, but still it is showing error that -  my-instance-template-with-custom-image was not found
I verified instance template name by executing this command - gcloud compute instance-groups managed list

Please show the results of gcloud compute instance-templates list. IIRC you will need to provide the full resource name for the template.
